# Permission denied (publickey) on AWS instance of Bitnami Wordpress

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I have an AWS instance of Bitnami Wordpress.

Trying to connect using this command:

```
ssh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 -i wordpress.pem bitnami@52.91.239.245 -v
```

I get this...

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 52.91.239.245 [52.91.239.245] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file wordpress.pem type -1
debug1: identity file wordpress.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 51:1d:50:cd:89:30:dc:7b:8d:17:85:f4:03:45:c1:54
debug1: Host '52.91.239.245' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/OWNER/.ssh/known_hosts:18
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: wordpress.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have .ssh permissions as follows:

```
sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
sudo chown -R OWNER ~/.ssh/
```

Does this mean the publickey was not found? That it could not be read?

Comment: Go to nano /Users/OWNER/.ssh/known_hosts and delete line number 18 and then try the SSH again

Comment: Did that and got this: Warning: Permanently added '52.91.239.245' (RSA) to the list of known hosts. Then ended with same last 13 lines as above.

Comment: Did you try normal SSH?

Comment: What do you mean by normal SSH?

Comment: Like ssh -i /<path-to-pem-file>/wordpress.pem bitnami@52.91.239.245

Comment: Tried... same result

Comment: Is it a ubuntu server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123017/discussion-between-user2197029-and-error2007s).

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the instance and started over. This time I created a new .pem instead of reusing an existing one. When I created the instance with that new .pem, I got in. I think reusing the .pem may have been the problem. Thanks for the help folks!